# Is defining the argument type in a Python's function a good habit?

Tags: python

I have picked up coding not longer than a year, primarily only coding in Python. I know this question has been asked, with mixed responses, but is defining the type of the argument in a Python Function a good habit?

For example,

```
def data_cleaning(df, conditions: list = None, choices: list = None, column_names: list = None):
    pass
```

I started to realize you can do this only recently, and I am excited to use it everywhere now. Is it a good thing? If yes, is there a guide anywhere that I can follow?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. It makes you think about what you're doing in advance a little more.

Comment: If you're not the only developer working on project - yes, it's good habit, as well as commenting code. If you're the only developer and project is not big - it's more time wasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you have resources to spend extra time on adding:

1. good function name;
2. detailed docstring;
3. type hints - to describe types of arguments and type of returned value.

And it's not only useful when you're working in the team. When you will return to your code in a year or two - it would be hard to understand:

1. what this function does;
2. what are those arguments about;
3. what's the output of this function;
4. does this function have some side-effects;
5. how to use that function.

BTW, in your case, type hints should be a bit different though:

```py
from typing import Optional, List


def data_cleaning(df, conditions: Optional[List] = None, choices: Optional[List] = None, column_names: Optional[List] = None):
    pass
```

More about `Optional`, `List` and other type hinting features here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

---

One day I faced such function in a Django project:

```py
def user(user_id, process):
    # very complicated logic inside: about 75loc
```

1. purpose of that function - to delete user correctly;
2. `user_id` is actually a place for `User` model instance (not for numeric id);
3. `process` is a boolean marker to tell the function is there's need to cleanup related things.

So I had to spend extra time to understand what's happening. The problem became worser because there were dozen of such functions. Much better to write something like:

```py
from typing import NoReturn

from app.models import User


def delete_user(user: User, cleanup_related: bool = True) -> NoReturn:
    """
    Main purpose of this function is to delete a user from System. Most of
    the time you also want to remove all related stuff as well. So that logic
    is enabled by default.

    Related things to be removed:
    1. profile (refer to app.models.Profile);
    2. all pending tasks from background queue.

    :param user: a `User` model instance to be deleted
    :param cleanup_related: if True, all the related things would be removed
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Note that `list` and the standard collections can be directly used instead of `typing.List` since Python 3.9. This also is backported to 3.7 and 3.8 by using `from __future__ import annotations` ([PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/))

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, is there any reason why we need to use typing library instead of just saying `list`

Comment: @ilovewt depends on the Python version you use. Niklas Mertsch did a good catch!

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev Thanks a lot for helping me out, I am reading through the documentation now, the example you provided was great, I assume `NoReturn` signifies the function does not need to return anything? Will there also be any difference between `Optional[List]` and `Optional[list]`?

Comment: @ilovewt yea, you're right `NoReturn` means that function will never return something https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn. And now I realize that in my case it's not a good choice. Because you know even if you don't have `return` statement explicitly - function still returns `None`. If my answer helped you, please mark it as "correct" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes debugging phase and collaborating with other developer easier. However, it is up to you of course, you can live without it.

If you want you can check this [link](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#pros-and-cons) for more info.