# How to Type Check in Python when Dictionary has different data Type

Tags: python

I have recently picked up the habit of doing type checking. You can see my [previous post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764447/is-defining-the-argument-type-in-a-pythons-function-a-good-habit/64764530?noredirect=1#comment114510749_64764530).
However I soon ran into a problem, my `target` argument is a `dict` with 7 key-value pairs but not all have the same type of data type. Is this syntax below the right way to do it? It seems very cumbersome to do so.

```
def augmentate(self, image: np.ndarray, target: [Dict[str, np.ndarray],
                                                 Dict[str, torch.Tensor],
                                                 Dict[str, torch.Tensor],
                                                 Dict[str, torch.Tensor],
                                                 Dict[str, torch.Tensor],
                                                 Dict[str, torch.Tensor],
                                                 Dict[str, torch.Tensor]]):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your intent.

```
target: Union[Dict[str, np.ndarray],Dict[str, torch.Tensor]]
```

is either a dictionary from a string to an ndarray or a dict from a string to a tensor.

```
 target: Dict[str, Union[np.ndarray, torch.Tensor]]
```

is a dictionary from a string to either an ndarray or a tensor.

So the former can be one of several types of homogeneous dictionaries, whereas the latter is a heterogeneous dictionary.

Comment: I am still slightly confused, in my case, which one should I use? The difference is not clear for me

Comment: It really depends on what you're planning. Will you ever pass a dict with more than a single value in it? Choose the second. No? Choose the first.

Answer (score 1):

Your type checking should describe all the types that your method is designed to handle. In your case, that appears to be two, which the Union type describes:

```
def augmentate(self, image: np.ndarray, target: Dict[str, Union[np.ndarray, torch.Tensor]]):
```

Comment: This still allows two types to be mixed up incorrectly right?